# django-threadedcomments to return number of comments excluding replies

Tags: django

I'm using

```
{% get_comment_count for OBJECT as CONTEXT_VAR %}:
```

to get the number of comments that an object has. The issue with this is that you can't limit it by depth. I want to be able to get for example the number of comments a specific object has had excluding the replies made to the comments it self.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your own templatetag or count them in the view and pass it to the template.